# jQuery division - find all price classes and divide

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, division

I have a page of items with various prices in GBP, each price is within a span with a class of price, what I would like to do is change the value of ALL the prices to that value divided by 1.2. so along the lines of

```
$('.price').html() / "1.2";
```

now i'm aware that this won't work as the format is £10,500 for example, I havent been able to find similar here but i'd like to take that £10,500 value divide it by 1.2 and have the value update to the result (£8,750). Anything I have tried thus far leaves me with NaN and i'm struggling to make progress.

Comment: You're struggling to make process because you haven't tried to look on Google. I would then look at the $.each() function and go from there.

Comment: Incorrect, I have looked on Google but thanks for a very unhelpful reply.

Comment: $.each() is the function you need...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a button for testing:

```
<button id="test-button">Test Currencies</button>
```

Add the following jQuery:

```
$('#test-button').on('click', function () {
    // Get currency elements
    var currencies = $('.price');
    var newSymbol = '£';
    var eRate = 0.8333;
    $.each(currencies, function (index, value) {
        // Change value to a number using regex
        var number = Number($(this).html().replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, ""));
        // Assign new value and add number formatting
        $(this).html(newSymbol + (number * eRate).toFixed(2).toLocaleString('en'));
    });

});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: @user4349555 Updated for post-processing number formatting

Comment: Pretty much hit the nail on the head, missing the comma but i'm sure i can crack that. Appreciate the comments to help me understand what is happening within the code.

Comment: Nice answer, yes! Well explained and very usefull, well done!

Comment: @user4349555 I've updated the code for the number of decimal places as well

Answer (score 0):

Here you go :-)

Tested and working.

```
$("span").each(function() 
{
var strNewString = $(this).html().replace(',','');
$(this).html(strNewString / 1.2);
});
```

Comment: Of course if you want the number formatted again with the "," you can do this afterwards. Ask if questions.

Comment: This results in all the values changing to "0" - would it be because the £ is within the value and not just numbers?

Comment: Ah, yes. - Is the £ inside the span? If possible you can set £ outside the span, and it'll work. Else you can replace this character with "empty" and add it again afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function format_price(_input_str){
 var input_str=_input_str+'';    //if input integer convert to string
 input_str=input_str.replace(new RegExp(' ',"g"), ''); //if exist spaces
 input_str=input_str.replace(new RegExp('&#163;',"g"), '');    //if exist simbil £
 input_str=input_str.replace(new RegExp('&nbsp;',"g"), ''); //if wxist &nbsp;
 var input_int = parseInt(input_str)||0;
 if(input_int==0){ return  _input_str;} //return original string
 input_str=input_int+'';
 var out_str='';
 while(input_str.length > 3){
   out_str=input_str.substr(-3)+'&nbsp;'+out_str;
   input_str=input_str.substr(0,input_str.length-3);
 }
 if(input_str.length>0){out_str=input_str+'&nbsp;'+out_str;}
 out_str='&#163;&nbsp;'+out_str;
 return out_str;
}




   $('.price').each(function(){
      var this_price=$(this).html();
      $(this).html(format_price(this_price));
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <div class="price">12345</div>
  <div class="price">76 09</div>
  <div class="price">4576 09</div>
  <div class="price">45</div>
  <div class="price">&#163;&nbsp;12&nbsp;345&nbsp;678&nbsp;</div>
```